# Is there a way to make a USB 3.0 flash drive bootable to Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

My flash drive recently broke and Kingston sent me a replacement which is USB 3.0.
Tried making it bootable but it isn't recognized.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Im guessing you need to include the drivers and specify them somehow?!?!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Do you want to boot the entire operating system from the flash drive, or just the installer?

Comment: How do you made the stick bootable. Are you using it in Superfloppy- or HDD (with partitions) mode?

Comment: I am trying to boot the installer, basically use it as an alternative to a DVD. I made the stick bootable by using DISKPART and sticking Windows 7 bootmgr on it.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to connect the USB-Stick to an USB 2.0 port. If your BIOS does not recognize it in USB 2.0 mode then you know that your problem is unrelated to the USB 3.0 subsystem.

Comment: I like your thinking! Tried that and it works. Based on that, is it possible to make a USB 3.0 device act as a USB 2.0 device?

Comment: Connect it via a USB 2.0 hub.

Comment: A simple hub or an USB2 adapter cable will (in most cases) not be enough. The important part is that the used port has to be connected to an USB port that is provided by your chipset. At the moment most USB3 ports are powered by 3rd party chips like those from Renesas and I assume that those chips do no support USB boot. Only from some AMD chipsets I know that they have integrated USB3 ports - on such systems boot from an USB3 port may work.

Comment: @Robert, I have a MacBook in which both the USB ports are both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0. I want to install Windows using a USB 3.0 pen drive. Is it possible?

Comment: @pratnala Sorry but Apple devices are a completely different "universe", I don't have any experience with those. I try to avoid everything from that company.

Comment: I couldn't avoid the hardware lol. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more that you need to update your BIOS, if there is an Update to add USB3.0 support.

Comment: Ive tried BIOS update but to no avail. The flaw is the main use of my USB drive is to use it as an Installation medium for Windows hence BIOS update every time would make the speed of the USB 3 pointless

Answer (score -1):

I don't think Windows 7 supports USB 3.0. As per official news Windows 8 will be supporting USB3.0 but I don't think windows 7 does that.http://www.techfanas.com/2011/part-i-whats-new-in-windows-8/